# EFCore, Is it possible to generate migration script without startup project?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-2.0

I have googled a lot, but didn't find any useful information about the question.

Currently, I'm making a plugin system, each plugin is a .Net Core 2.2 **ClassLibrary** project.

In one plugin, it's going to create a new DbContext. To be able to deploy to production environment, I need to create migration script. But I just can't call Add-Migration or Script-Migration without the startup project.

Finally, We come up with a dummy startup project just for generating the script. However, the script doesn't include any connection info:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[__EFMigrationsHistory]') IS NULL
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE [__EFMigrationsHistory] (
    [MigrationId] nvarchar(150) NOT NULL,
    [ProductVersion] nvarchar(32) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK___EFMigrationsHistory] PRIMARY KEY ([MigrationId])
);
END;

GO

CREATE TABLE [Blogs] (
    [BlogId] int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Url] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Blogs] PRIMARY KEY ([BlogId])
);

-- omit some similar code

CREATE INDEX [IX_Posts_BlogId] ON [Posts] ([BlogId]);

GO

INSERT INTO [__EFMigrationsHistory] ([MigrationId], [ProductVersion])
VALUES (N'20190318085448_InitialCreate', N'2.2.3-servicing-35854');

GO
```

I don't understand the point to have a startup project. Is there any workaround? Thanks.

Comment: How are you deploying on the production ? This question comes in my mind because to execute database script, your application will need a startup so that it can execute any migration during the first start of the application, and you specify which dbContext to use in the startup file. Usually people actually generate the scripts and then use manual/automated execution of the scripts (before/after code deployment) via setting up continuous deployment (jenkins/devops).

Comment: We have a powershell script to run all the db scripts if any. The powershell script in charge of connectting to the right db and will execut before deploying to the test/stage/production environment.